# English vocabulary/ prepositions

Tags: vocabulary

I need your help. Could you please tell me which one of these is correct?

> A. I'm going out to the garden to pick some beans ***for*** it's not
>   raining.
>
> B. I'm going out to the garden to pick some beans ***while*** it's not
>   raining.

I assume that the first one is correct, because ***for*** in this case has the meaning of "due to the fact that". 
Please tell me what you think about this. Your answer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework question? if so, please say so and provide a bit more detail on the research you've done to answer the question.

Comment: Totally agree with Brad. The philosophy forum is having a similar issue with people who visit these sites just to answer homework questions.

Comment: And don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: it's not a homework question, it's a "London school of English testing" question. and i was just wondering what the correct answer was, i haven;t done anything wrong, i just asked a question, okay?

Comment: You need to find out what prepositions are, for a start.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `for`, it should have a comma:

> I'm going out to the garden to pick some beans, for it's not raining.

That means that you do it *because* it's not raining.

> I'm going out to the garden to pick some beans while it's not raining.

That means that you will do it during the time that it is not raining.

Which sentence you use depends on your purpose.

Comment: And on whether you want to sound natural. Using 'for' = 'because' (or better, 'as') here makes you sound like a character in _Pride and Prejudice_.